# Motor works with battery but squeaks with H bridge

Tags: arduino, dc-motor, h-bridge

I have a 4 channel H bridge and 4 DC brushed motors. 2 rayovac 6v batteries.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B09T9V7H5P?psc=1&ref=ppx_pop_mob_b_asin_title](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09T9V7H5P)

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B09KL763ZG?psc=1&ref=ppx_pop_mob_b_asin_title](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09KL763ZG)

Two motors are working normally when I connect them either directly with batteries or through the h bridge.

The other two motors are working normally directly with batteries. If I replace the first two motors with these other two when connecting to H bridge, the two motors are not spinning but just making a sharp noise.

What could be wrong? Defective motors?  Or inadequate batteries?

Comment: Please post the circuit/schematic diagram for one H-bridge channel. Please also state what PWM frequency is being used.

Comment: 12 V, stall current 2.8 mA, `original speed: 110000rpm` lo and behold - typos, if not carelessness.

Comment: The motor "back shield" (? that round "lid" with brush holders & brushes) may have three mounting position, one each favourable for clockwise&ccw operation, respectively, and a neutral one. There seems to be no SE site for models that don't fly?!

Comment: Are those motors labelled? Any differences between pairs?